# Translation audio live streaming

Tags: audio

We are trying to stream a live audio feed of a translator at events. Basically a person is speaking and there is a translator sitting in a booth talking into a mic we want users to be able to get that translated audio feed on thier smartphone with, preferably a small amount of latency. Since it is a live speaker a minor amount can be tolerated. But it can't be major.

Ideally I was hoping for something like open broadcaster with a matching app for the phones. But I'll take any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [IceCast2](http://icecast.org) to stream the audio. IceCast just taks sound provided to it, and creates a stream that can be played by clients. If you need some sort of logic that decide what to play and when, [Liquidsoap](http://savonet.sourceforge.net) is an excellent choice.

On the client side, you could just embed an audio player on a website and it should work on most phones. If you want an app, I would suggest creating the web page as a [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Web_Apps), allowing users to install the webpage on their phone. Alternatively you could ask your users to use an existing media player app, and create a user friendly URL for your stream. For example, lets say you have the domain example.com with IceCast running on port 8080. If your stream is at *example.com:8080/mystream.ogg*, you could for example create mystream.example.com and redirect it to example.com:8080/mystream.ogg.

If you want a really simple tool for streaming audio from you computer to IceCast, and you use windows, you can use [butt](http://danielnoethen.de). I imagine there exists similar software for macOS and Linux.